# While loop with nested if statement won't loop javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I don't understand why, but my loop won't complete. I am supposed to make a guessing game using javascript but the loop won't actually loop. It just takes an answer, displays the appropriate window and stops. Regardless of the answer. Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome To The JS Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<script> 

//Initialize the variables that will be needed.
var target;
var target_index;
var guess_input;
var guesses=0;
var finished=false;
var guesses=0;
var colors = ["blue", "cyan", "gold", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];

function do_game() {
    var random_number = (Math.random()*colors.length);
    var random_number=Math.floor(random_number);
    target=colors[random_number];
    alert(target);
    while (!finished){
        guess_input=prompt("I am thinking of a color in the list below. Can you guess which color?"+"\n\n"+ colors.join() );
        guesses++;
        if (guess_input!=target){
            alert("no")
            return true;
        }
        alert("yes!!")
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="do_game()">
</body>
</html>
```

Now I really don't understand what i am doing wrong, and the console flags up no error in any browser :/ 
I would really appreciate the help!

Cheers,

David

Comment: Set `finished` to `true` in the loop..

Comment: The `return true` exits the function and thus won't continue the loop. You could replace it with `continue` or use an `else` structure. Using return makes the finished variable obsolete, so you could just use while(true)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're breaking out of the `while` loop when an incorrect answer is entered and you run the code:

```
if (guess_input!=target){
    alert("no")
    return true;
}
```

Rather than returning a value, consider using a `continue` statement.

```
if (guess_input!=target){
    alert("no")
    continue;
}
```

This will jump to the next iteration of the loop, staying within the loop but not executing the `alert("yes!!")`. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snwLvu6h/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

(And as per comments on your question, you don't really need the `finished` variable, just using `while(true)` should be sufficient.)

Answer (score 0):

Set `finished` to `true` (no need to set it to `false` as it will always be `false` until you change it). If you need to return `finished` after the loop (which I don't think you do), I've added in the statement to that effect. You also need to have an `else` clause in there too or `finished` will be set to `true` in your code even if the condition was met.

```
function do_game() {
    var random_number = (Math.random()*colors.length);
    var random_number=Math.floor(random_number);
    target=colors[random_number];
    while (!finished){
        guess_input=prompt("I am thinking of a color in the list below. Can you guess which color?"+"\n\n"+ colors.join() );
        guesses++;
        if (guess_input!=target){
            alert("no");
        } else {
          alert("yes!!");
          finished = true;
        }
    }
    return finished;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were returning a boolean regardless of the condition. Take a look a the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/zmdcL4h4/1/

```
//Initialize the variables that will be needed.
var target;
var target_index;
var guess_input;
var guesses=0;
var finished=false;
var guesses=0;
var colors = ["blue", "cyan", "gold", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];

function do_game() {
    var random_number = (Math.random()*colors.length);
    var random_number=Math.floor(random_number);
    target=colors[random_number];
    alert(target);
    while (!finished){
        guess_input=prompt("I am thinking of a color in the list below. Can you guess which color?"+"\n\n"+ colors.join() );
        if(!guess_input){
            finished = true;
            return true;
        }
        guesses++;
        if (guess_input!=target){
            alert("no")
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Your code displays both no and yes.. Also I want it to stop when the correct answer is reached.

Comment: I updated the code. you weren't very clear on what you wanted to happen